# css on a and a:hover not working

Tags: html, css

I am not sure where I am going wrong but the css on a and a:hover doesnt seem to work. I cant see the background of the li elements changing to blue when I hover over them.Can anyone help? Any help will be really appreciated.

The HTML is

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">nature</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">travel</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">people</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">random</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">bio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
 </body>
```

the CSS is

```
#navbar ul{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    width:600px;
    list-style : none;
    padding-top:30px;
 }

 #navbar ul li
 {
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
      text-align:center;
      font-family: Calibri;
      padding-left:15px;
      font-size:20px;
      font-weight:normal;
      list-style-type: none;
      color:#808080;
}

#navbar ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     color: #666;
 }

 #navbar ul li a : hover 
 {
     color:#FFFF00;
     background-color: #4caef2; 
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add random spaces in selectors.

This is an error:

```
#navbar ul li a : hover
```

Remove all the spaces except the actual descendant combinators:

```
#navbar ul li a:hover
```

This would have been picked up if you had [used a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Thank you so much..this works..Thanks also for providing information about the validator

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the space b/w colon and hover ie,

## navbar ul li a : hover  should be #navbar ul li a:hover

Answer (score 1):

change

```
#navbar ul li a : hover
```

to

```
#navbar ul li a:hover
```

please

if you want to apply a pseudo class like *hover* you have to append it directly after the selector you are applying the pseudclass to, separated by a `':'` without any additional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for pseudo-classes is :

```
selector:pseudoclass
```

So in your case :

```
#navbar ul li a:hover
```